# Can't get Selenium to work on Raspberry Pi zero headless

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to run a Selenium Python script on my RP Zero w running Raspbian.

I tried multiple methods so far and still getting this error every time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/imageRecGoogle/image_rec_google/seleniumAddToApex.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 84, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 100, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 113, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -4
```

Sample code to repreduce the issue:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()
opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opts.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
opts.add_argument('--disable-setuid-sandbox')
browser = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver", options=opts)
```

OR

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1600, 1200))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
```

Running the command:
`chromium-browser`
results in:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(zenity:2011): Gtk-WARNING **: 03:38:57.601: cannot open display:
```

This is what I've did so far:
(I've removed everything to get a fresh install of everything)

```
pip uninstall selenium
sudo apt purge --remove chromium-browser chromium chromium-chromedriver -y
sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean -y

sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver --yes
sudo apt-get install xvfb --yes
pip install PyVirtualDisplay xvfbwrapper selenium
```

Comment: what does `/usr/bin/chromedriver` return you as an error?